# Why are my cookies undercooked in commercial oven?

Tags: baking, cookies, convection

I have recently started using a commercial kitchen to make chocolate chip cookies (and other similar types of cookies). The kitchen has a Blodgett double deck convection oven. The problem is even if the cookie looks done on the outside, the inside is undercooked and gooey. I am able to bake in my home oven on a convection setting at 325 degrees F. When I tested that in the commercial kitchen, the cookies were basically raw inside. 
I've tried different temperatures all the way from 200 degrees to 325 and I still don't get cookies that are good in the middle. I'm not sure what to do at this point...should I let them cool for longer? The sheet is cool before I remove a cookie.

Comment: (1) I looked at a couple of recipes. All specified 350 F or 375 F. (2) Did you check the oven temperature of both ovens with a thermometer?

Comment: Can you try  disabling the fan and use the oven "convection-less" ?

Comment: @MaxW I did and am getting an accurate reading on both. I've tried increasing and decreasing the temperature, but nothing has worked so far

Comment: @Max Unfortunately, that's not an option with this oven

Comment: Have you tried higher than 325? You specify that your temperature range stops there, what happens if you go hotter?

Comment: Are you using identical ingredients?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple things to troubleshoot here.

1. <strike>Check that the oven is working. you can buy an in oven thermometer to verify that you are getting accurate readings.</strike> seems you have done this already.
2. Could the oven be steam-injection? that could cause some problems with done-ness.
3. Maybe some other part of your process is different now that you are working in an commercial kitchen. Note [act 14 in this episode](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/241/20-acts-in-60-minutes), small things you change can have huge ramifications (in this case not letting the meat rest for a short time lead to a drastic reduction in flavor and color).

Answer (score 2):

There's something else that you may need to test -- how many pans you have in the oven at one time.

Most home ovens only have two racks, so you're never cooking more than two sheets of cookies at a time.  This means that they'll have radiant heat from either the top of bottom.  Some cookie recipes are so sensitive to radiant heat that they'll specifically mention that you should only cook one sheet of cookies at a time.

And as you say that the outside of the cookies is done before the inside, this typically means that you need to turn down the temperature slightly, but increase the cooking time.  You may want to just adjust your recipe in this way, so you can make proper use of the commercial oven, rather than trying to figure out what to modify to make the commercial oven behave like your home oven.